# Why is the complexity of the following nested loop O(n√n)?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am not able to figure out the complexity of the below code. Though, I know the correct answer. Just wondering why is that so.

```
void main()
{
    int i, j, n, x;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j*j <= n; j++)
        {
           x=10;
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity is O(n√n).

Comment: If we ignore that n is not initialized to a value. Since x always becomes 10, a good compiler would just remove the loops and set x to 10 directly so there is no complexity.

Comment: @Johan Emmm.... There is no such thing as "no complexity". It's called O(1)

Comment: @Johan Even a good compiler should not do so if executed with `-O0` :-)

Comment: There is not even need to assign `x`, since it is a local variable. The program has no observable side effects.

Answer (score 3):

The outer loop performs `n` iterations.

The inner loop performs `sqrt(n)` iterations (since it compares `j` *squared* to `n`).

The loop body takes constant time.

Multiplying all three gives `O(n sqrt(n))`.

P.S. A good compiler will probably produce `O(1)` code for this exact loop.

Comment: How do you conclude the `sqrt(n)` here? Both loops run from 0 to `n` and `n` is not being modified.

Comment: @Wolph: The terminal conditions are different (one uses `i` and the other uses the square of `j`).

Answer (score 2):

First loop can go from 1 to n and second loop will go from 1 to sqrt(n) ..
that's why the complexity is O(n*sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 1):

The outer loop is O(n) - the execution time is proportional to the number of elements.

But it has an inner loop which executes once for each iteration of the outer loop. This one stops when the square of the number or executions is equals n. That is, it executes √n times for each iteration of the outer loop.

The total complexity is therefore O(n x √n), written as O(n√n).

Answer (score 0):

Draw a table and you'll know why. Suppose `n = 10`:

```
  i  |  j  
-----+-----
  0  |  0   0*0 <= 10 ? Yes  |                |
  0  |  1   1*1 <= 10 ? Yes  |                | 
  0  |  2   2*2 <= 10 ? Yes  | → O(√n) Times  |
  0  |  3   3*3 <= 10 ? Yes  |                | 
  0  |  4   4*4 <= 10 ? NO!  |                |
  1  |  0   ...                               | 
  1  |  1                                     | → O(n) Times
  .. | ..                                     |
  .. | ..                                     |
  9  |  0                                     |
  9  |  1                                     |
  9  |  2                                     |
  9  |  3                                     |
  9  |  4                                     |
```

Now you observe that the inner loop performs O(√n) times. The outer loop is straightforward, it takes O(n). Multiplying them yields the result you're getting.

Comment: Where are you getting the `4*4 <= 10` from? That's not in the code I see? Did I miss an edit?

Comment: @Wolph I fixed `n` to be 10 for the sake of the example.

Comment: @Wolph I thought this might help OP to better understand the flow :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Sigma notation, you can obtain the exact number of iterations plus the order of growth complexity (Empirically verified):

[image]